# list <li> items in order of object value from lowest to highest

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I have an input value(listText) which is being compared to an object value (item.name). If they're equal I want to get the value of item.category and append the li's from lowest category number to highest. If input value does doesn't equal item.name it get a category value of 0 and display first on list.

```js
$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {

  if (event.which === 13) {

    //grab new list item from input
    var listText = $(this).val();
    $(this).val("");


    for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
      //make sure text input value matches item name 
      if (listText === item[i].name) {
        //create new li and add to ul 
        $("ul").append("<li>" + "<span>X</span> " + listText + " " + item[i].category + "</li>");
        return
      }
    }

    item.category = 0;
    $("ul").append("<li>" + "<span>X</span> " + listText + " " + item.category + "</li>");
  }
});


var item = [{
    name: "chicken",
    category: 3
  },
  {
    name: "milk",
    category: 2
  },
  {
    name: "garlic",
    category: 1
  },
  {
    name: "peppers",
    category: 1
  },
  {
    name: "bread",
    category: 2
  }
];
```

Comment: `return` will terminate the function it is in.  Not just the for loop it is in.  **The entire function**.  Is that what you want?

Comment: Otherwise, what's the issue?

Comment: Your question is confused. Can you add more details? What do you really want?

Answer (score 2):

- Filter using [RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- Sort using [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [String.prototype.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)
- Create the HTML String concatenation using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- PS: don't forget to [.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) your value (you don't want spaces to account)
- PS<sub>2</sub>: Use [KeyboardEvent key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key). Humans read code. Machines are doing fine.

```js
const items = [{
  name: "chicken",
  category: 3
}, {
  name: "milk",
  category: 2
}, {
  name: "garlic",
  category: 1
}, {
  name: "peppers",
  category: 1
}, {
  name: "bread",
  category: 2
}];

const sortBy = (arr, prop) => arr.sort((a, b) => ('' + a[prop]).localeCompare(b[prop]));

$("input[type='text']").on("keydown", function(event) {

  if (event.key !== "Enter") return; // "Enter", we're humans ;)
  
  event.preventDefault();
  const val = this.value.trim();
  
  // FILTER
  const items_filtered = items.filter(item => new RegExp(val, 'i').test(item.name) );
  // SORT
  const items_sorted = sortBy(items_filtered, "category");
  // CREATE LIST
  const items_LIs = items_sorted.reduce((html, item, i) => (html += `<li><span>${item.name}</span> Category: ${item.category}</li>`, html), "");
  // APPEND LIST
  $("ul").empty().append(items_LIs.length ? items_LIs : "<li><i>No results</i></li>");

});
```

```html
Type some text and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd><br>
<input type="text">
<ul></ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```